# How to access Excel data by random column's name text like name, phone, email, address in CodeIgniter

Tags: excel, codeigniter, import

How do I access Excel data by column's first row cell text like name, email, address in CodeIgniter?

***Note***: As you can see in the image first the place of `email` and in the second image the place of `email` so how I can access the data of email column because column's sequence are random this is not sure which comes first.

**Snapshot 1: First Type Column Sequence in Sheet**

[image: first type column sequence in sheet]

**Snapshot 2: Second Type Column Sequence in Sheet**

[image: second type column sequence in sheet]

Comment: the best practice in exel data processing is to give an option to download template exel and demand user to give the data in the same format